# Make a link inactive after 30 minutes or once it is used

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter so could'nt find a proper way on how to make a link valid for only 30 minutes. Like when user forget password, he ask for link to generate new password. I want that link to be valid for only 30 minutes, and once he changed his password he won't be able to use that link again.

Comment: You say you have not find a way to do it, that means you have tried? What have you tried? We need to know what you have tried to answer your question

Comment: i searched in web n tried to look for a proper logic on how to implement and make a link valid in codeigniter for some time. But I could'nt get any.

Answer (score 1):

When you send forgot password link,that time store datetime in your db. And when user click it check time range(send time and clicked time) from your db.for once use set flag(column is_password_set) value .And again check that flag from your db.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I will try to implement this. Thanks Shubham Azad

Comment: Soory i but i could'nt get the flag thing. How to check that flag?

Comment: when user click on link, check in your db a column that names as (is_password_set) . its' default value is 0.and when user set his password set it column value with 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would crate JWT token (JWT token with unique user id and expiration time).

Then use this token as a parameter for the url, for example

```
www.yoursite.com/changepassword/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi.eyJrZXkiOi.eUiabuiKv
```

Now using the controller for that page depending JWT token expiration time, & user id, either generate your password change page, or show them and expiration error etc...

If you need more info just ask.

[How to create JWT token using PHP.](https://dev.to/robdwaller/how-to-create-a-json-web-token-using-php-3gml)

Comment: So by this can i generate jwt token?

Comment: follow this blog [JWT token genataion in PHP](https://rbrt.wllr.info/2018/01/29/how-create-json-web-token-php.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you again!!